# Running a function using setInterval and clearInterval when conditions are met?

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I am not sure if this is the best way to do this or even if I am doing this right. I have a toggle switch that can be on and off, so when it is on it runs the function autoAdmit() once in a while and when it's switched off then it should not be running it. How should I do this? I don't know what's the best way to do this so I tried maybe the dumbest way to go at it..

```
function autoAdmit() {
    for (let element of document.getElementsByTagName('span')) {
        if (element.innerHTML === 'Admit') {
            element.click();
            }
        }
        
  
      
} 


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var checkbox = document.querySelector('#auto-admit .mdc-switch__native-control');

    function isChecked() {
      if (checkbox.checked) {
        
        clearInterval(autoAdmit)
        setInterval(autoAdmit, 1000)

      } else {
    
        clearInterval(autoAdmit)
        setInterval(autoAdmit, 10000000000000)
        
      }
    }
    checkbox.addEventListener('change', function() {
      isChecked();
    });
  }

);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.the return value of setInterval is a number(interval Id),when you'd like to clearInterval, params should be the interval Id.

2.if you don't want it to autoAdmit, just clearInterval, no need to setInterval with a long time.

3.i don't replace your autoAdmit function, as i think, no need to querySelect for 'Admit' element every time(that is not a big problem).

```
let clickIntervalId = null;

function autoAdmit() {
    for (let element of document.getElementsByTagName('span')) {
        if (element.innerHTML === 'Admit') {
            element.click();
        }
    }      
} 

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var checkbox = document.querySelector('#auto-admit .mdc-switch__native-control');
    function isChecked() {
      if (checkbox.checked) {
        if(clickIntervalId) clearInterval(clickIntervalId);
        clickIntervalId = setInterval(autoAdmit, 1000);
      } else {
        clearInterval(clickIntervalId);
      }
    }
    checkbox.addEventListener('change', function() {
      isChecked();
    });
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var timer = null

function autoAdmit() {
    for (let element of document.getElementsByTagName('span')) {
        if (element.innerHTML === 'Admit') element.click();
    }
} 

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    let checkbox = document.querySelector('#auto-admit .mdc-switch__native-control')
    checkbox.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
        clearInterval(timer)
        if(event.target.checked){
            timer = setInterval(autoAdmit, 1000)
        }
    });
});
```